# How can you echo the existing settings in Vim?

Tags: vim

So I'm working on updating my .vimrc file since it's a gigantic mess currently. What I'd like to be able to do is give a command to vim to get it to echo the existing settings.

For example, in my .vimrc I have

```
set shortmess += r
```

Now, going off of the help file, I know that shortmess has currently more options turned on than r - but I don't know what they are! How do I get vim to echo the currently active settings to me?

Comment: `:map` is also handy to display all the key mapping definitions. It is not options `per se` but it is useful to not miss something while refactoring your .vimrc

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`:set`, or if you just want that one option, `:set shortmess?`.

Answer (score 14):

Two ways:

```
echo &shortmess
```

or

```
set shortmess
```

Comment: Ah, I forgot about [`&`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#:let-&).  But I would recommend against the latter (use `?`) because of what it does to boolean options.

Comment: ephemient: What does `&` do to boolean options, does it do anything more than show 1 or 0?  Also, is there a difference between `set shortmess` and `set shortmess?`.

Comment: when you echo a boolean option it will return a 1 or a 0.  ephemient was saying not to use `set shortmess` because that will actually change a boolean option.  He was recommending to use `set shortmess?` instead.

Comment: Using `set someoption?` is better than echo, as echo does not work well with boolean options, returning an error message if it is not set. Example: if wrap is set, then `echo nowrap` will return an error, whereas `set nowrap?` will return `wrap`.